# How to get input from a function in Python and print in tkinter GUI?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *

def printSomething():
    inputValue=textBox.get("1.0","end-1c")
    res=response(inputValue)
    label = Label(root, text=res)
    #this creates a new label to the GUI
    label.pack() 

root = Tk()

button = Button(root, text="Print Me", command=printSomething) 
button.pack()
textBox=Text(root, height=2, width=10)
textBox.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

I have written a python code that returns text. and print that in tkinter label.while i try to execute it shows "None" in label.

Comment: What do you think `response()` is doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would probably be better to create the label in the global namespace once and then just update the label every time you press the button.

I also recommend using `import tkinter as tk` vs `from tkinter import *` as it provides better maintainability as your code grows and you do not end up overwriting built in methods.

I have updated your code and changed a few things to better fit the [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) standard.

```
import tkinter as tk


def print_something():
    label.config(text=text_box.get("1.0", "end-1c"))

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text="Print Me", command=print_something).pack()
text_box = tk.Text(root, height=2, width=10)
text_box.pack()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Just changing your line:

```
res = response(inputValue)
```

to

```
res = inputValue
```

worked for me, creating a new label every time I pressed the button.

Comment: Unless the response() function exists in your code and does something important to the content of your textbox, this solution will work.